# Can I use plantuml proxy url for private project in gitlab?

Tags: proxy, gitlab, plantuml

I tried using http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/proxy?cache=no&src=file.txt, where file.txt is source of plantuml diagram inside my project. I wanted to use this url as parameter for link inside markdown file as [uml http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/proxy?cache=no&src=file.txt](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/proxy?cache=no&src=file.txt), to have diagram shown in markdown file. But it works only for public text files, and I would like to have that file.txt inside my private project where markdown file with proxy url would be as well, is there a solution for private projects?

Comment: Are you using a self-hosted GitLab instance or gitlab.com? But in general, no, I don't think you can safely use the plantuml _proxy_ for private repos. But you probably can setup your own plantuml server.

Comment: I use gitlab.com

Comment: I think you *can* by putting the token in the URL (I don't use GitLab, but there's a token on the image in GitHub). Anyway, that is not very fun to do, since every time you change the image, the token changes and you must update the URL.